# javafx - KeyEvent.getCharacter() returns null-terminated character

Tags: java, user-interface, events, javafx

I have a follwing problem with KeyEvent handling in javafx 2.0. This code in the start method:

```
scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, e -> System.out.format(
                        "Type: {%s},\tCode: {%s},\tchar: {%s}%n", 
                        e.getEventType(), e.getCode(), e.getCharacter());
);
```

produces:

```
Type: {KEY_PRESSED},    Code: {A},          char: {
Type: {KEY_TYPED},      Code: {UNDEFINED},  char: {a}
Type: {KEY_RELEASED},   Code: {A},          char: {
```

(same with other keys and method `e.setOnKey{Pressed, Released, Typed}()`)

Looks like `e.getCharacter()` returns `'\0'`. Where is the problem? In my app I need to get the code and the value of a typed key at once. Interestingly, a few days ago a construction with `KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` works pretty well.

USECASE:
I'm scanning keyboard input from a barcode scanner, which ends each code with enter (which I have to distinguish from other characters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getCharacter` method only returns meaningful data for `KEY_TYPED` events, [see javadoc (emphasis mine)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html):

> The character variable always contains a valid Unicode character(s) or `CHAR_UNDEFINED`. Character input is reported by key typed events; ***key pressed and key released events are not necessarily associated with character input***. Therefore, the character variable is guaranteed to be meaningful only for key typed events.

`CHAR_UNDEFINED` contains `"\u0000"` which is why you get this result.

Comment: Oh, I've missed that during last docs browsing. What could be the solution? Is there any way to fit my needs, which are to capture any key put in the whole app into the buffer and save a string when enter was hit?

Comment: @saleph Use an `onTyped` handler to fill the buffer and an `onPressed` handler to handle the "Enter" key.